# Strip html to end up with linebreak-delimited list

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I want to create database location records in mySQL. I have the following html string from a select box:

```
<cfset x='  
<option value="1188">Aka Aka</option><option value="346">Ararimu</option><option value="293">Awhitu</option><option value="2851">Bombay</option><option value="865">Buckland</option>
'>
```

Rather than manually enter the records in the database, I'd like to strip out the html tags and end up with the following:

```
Aka Aka
Ararimu
Awhitu
Bombay
Buckland
```

Then I could do a simple loop based on line breaks and enter the data programatically. I can probably handle that part, but what I need to know is the simplest way to strip out the html to end up with the line break delimited list.

Comment: The simplest way to solve these types of problems is to avoid them.  In this case, put some effort into that select box so it gives you better data.

Comment: Obviously. We all dream of perfect data in the most perfect format. But in this case, not possible. I have to work with what I have.

Answer (score 6):

Here you go:

```
<cfset x='  
<option value="1188">Aka Aka</option><option value="346">Ararimu</option><option value="293">Awhitu</option><option value="2851">Bombay</option><option value="865">Buckland</option>
'>

<cfset y = ListToArray(x, "</option>", "false", "true") />

<cfset z = ArrayNew(1) />    

<cfloop array="#y#" index="name">
    <cfif Trim(ListLast(name, ">")) is not "">
        <cfset temp = ArrayAppend(z, ListLast(name, ">")) />    
    </cfif>
</cfloop>

<cfdump var="#z#" />
```

you have them in a *'z'* array now, you can convert to list and add line break delimiters if you really want to.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks very much!